# How to update react state in second tab of browser if I update state in browser first tab

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I just wanted to know is there any way to update state in the first tab then it will also update in the second tab in the browser

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't access to another tab in the browser. This would be a security breach on the client side. 
In each tab React is rendered from new and unaware of any other tab.
so you can't share React state between two tabs

You can use the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) and add a listener to `StorageEvent` (to handle the change) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/StorageEvent

Comment: If I do this using localStorage still I have to refresh the second tab in browser is it right?

Comment: No. you don't need to refresh, the localStorage automatically updated.